# AWS parse SES emails stored in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm receiving emails to SES which are then being automatically put in an S3 bucket.

I'm trying to figure out how to parse the emails for downstream processes using a lambda function which I've got started from a template.

Ideally I'd be able to get the recipient email address and any attachments. I'd also like to be able to get an image or a PDF of the email itself.

Is that possible?  I've tried a few things but running into problems because teh content type is an octet/stream:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        print("CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])
        return response['ContentType']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```